# MVC - Unable to Reference Items from dbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a View called EventDetails, called with the following:

```
    public IActionResult EventDetails(int eID)
    {
        var events = context.Events;
        Event e = new Models.Event();
        foreach (Event i in events)
        {
            if (i.EventID.Equals(eID)) { e = i; }
            Console.WriteLine(eID + "   " + i.EventID);
        }
        ViewBag.isYours = false;
        if (e.Artist.Equals(userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)))
        {
            ViewBag.isYours = true;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

`context` is an ApplicationDbContext, which includes `DbSet`s of Genres, Events, and ApplicationUsers. `EventDetails` is called with `<a asp-action="EventDetails" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id=@anEvent.EventID>@anEvent.EventName</a>` where `anEvent` is an element of an IEnumerable set of Events. (Passed in as ex ".../Home/EventDetails/2".)

When `EventDetails` is called, it seems that `eID` is left empty, as it does not appear in the Autos window with other items. Similarly, context.Events does not display any records in the Autos window.

What is the most likely cause of these errors?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Change it to `public IActionResult EventDetails(int ID)`

Comment: That didn't fix it, I'm afraid; the error still occurs after changing the variable name to `ID`.

Comment: I don't see how you can claim it 'empty' - its not marked a nullable parameter (`int? ID`) so you would be just throwing an exception. And so you have a specific route defined for that method?

Comment: I don't know then, maybe the issue is somewhere else. I've added a screenshot from the editor; the window in the bottom-left seems to display all active variables, but `ID` is not present.

Comment: What do you mean _it is not present_? What is the value of the parameter `int ID` when you debug your code. And what in the world are you using that loop for. Just use `Event e = context.Events.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EventID == ID);` (and test if `e` is `null`)

Comment: I mean that unless there's some other debug window I'm not aware of, `ID` *isn't there*. It's not on the top-level display, and it isn't under `this` either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130908/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-passage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the async version of getuser `userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)` and it is returning before it has a chance to get the result for you.

Either change it to the synchronous version or use `await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)`.

I think what you really want is something along the lines of the following:

```
public async IActionResult EventDetails(int eID)
{
    Event model = new Models.Event();
    var event = context.Events.Include(evt => evt.Artist)
                              .FirstOrDefault(evt => evt.EventID = eID);
    if (event == null) 
    {
       // return error
    }
    else
    {
       ViewBag.isYours = false;
       var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
       if (user == null)
       {
          // return error
       }
       if (event.Artist.SomeProperty == user.SomeProperty)
       {
           ViewBag.isYours = true;
           // Populate `model` properties with data from `event`
       }
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Changing to `GetUserId(HttpContext.User)` appears to have had no effect. The problem begins before that line is called, when `e.Artist` fails to gather its contents.

Comment: Missing an `Include` perhaps?

Comment: So it would seem; everything except `Genre` is now populating correctly, but adding an Include and changing the .Equals() to == of the IDs seems to have fixed Artist, per Stephen Muecke.

Comment: Include will populate the navigation property. Equals was comparing object references which will not work in this case, what you want is to compare the IDs.

Comment: Your code does show the use of Genre anywhere, but again, you probably just missing another include.

Comment: Yes. Adding the second Include got it working. Accepting this answer.